# How can the actual count of those eligible to vote be determined?

Tags: discussion, election

In the election chat room I gave a count of the number of users allowed to vote: 126 users. I did this by looking at the [users page](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users) and just counting them by hand. It started a series of others calculating the number and getting different answers. I am thrilled that it inspired others to take notice. Since we are getting different numbers and some are using what I would consider a more accurate means of counting ([ref](https://data.stackexchange.com/proofassistants/query/1572730/number-of-users-above-the-given-reputation?reputation=150)) the question is as the title.

> How can the actual count of those eligible to vote be determined?

---

A related question if the number is different than what can be derived by counting the users page is why a difference in the two ways? E.g. Are there people allowed to vote that are not showing up on the users page? etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing one of the easiest ways is to go to the users tab, [sort by reputation, all time](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), and then count. Each page is 4x9, so 36 people and you can add it up pretty quickly.

As of right now, you have three full pages plus 18 extra on page 4. That's 108+18 = 126. It requires a bit of math but it's more reliable than SEDE since that's only updated weekly.

Comment: @GuyCoder Area51 says [150 have 200+](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants) reputation, so that's more than the claim that 126 have >= 150.

Comment: @Rob Did you see `We recommend:` in the line before `150 users with 200+ rep (on pace for 154 users at 90 days)`?

Comment: @GuyCoder so you didn't notice that [all the values are incorrect](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)  --- In your quest to prove my statement untrue you failed to notice anything else, let's not continue.

Comment: @Rob Could you further describe how the values in your link are incorrect? I checked some of the user profiles and I think the numbers are (at least mostly) correct on the "all" tab. You could check some of the possible problems [listed in comments here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171593/419414).

Comment: @bub, no. This was a lengthy back and forth, the excess comments were deleted by Catija, leaving what is there now; let's not restart.

Comment: Oh, sorry then.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Stack Exchange API for this to get the **live number** of eligible voters, because there is a `min` (reputation) field.

Current result -- [image]

Example use of the API:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#min=150&filter=!40CXOUq0axmHYcgDp&site=proofassistants&run=true

---

The [ElectionBot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10555677/electionbot?tab=profile), when set up in the election chat room, also gets the number of eligible voters this way, and is able to return the number of users who are eligible, as well as the number who has already voted for that election.

[Example chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60768286#60768286):

> Based on the number of Constituent badges awarded, 57 (44.53% of 128 eligible) users have voted so far.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. You're a diamond moderator on SO right? On that site, it's not preferred to display hyperlinks instead of URLs?

Comment: Well, the URL query parameters is important to the answer.

Comment: I see. So basically the way to use the API, is to change the URL (e.g. `proofassistants` changes to `stackoverflow` and `150` changes to `3000`)? There's no other way to run the API with different parameters? Also, I guess you didn't actually answer the question, about whether or not it's preferred to display hyperlinks instead of URLs on SO (in cases where the URL doesn't contain query parameters or something with a similar level of importance).

Comment: Correct, that's how it's done. No, there's no link display preference as far as I'm aware of.